# New domain - Can ping Netbios and IP, but not FQDN (errors joining name)

Tags: dns, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I am having issues with my DNS.  I am setting up a new domain and have Windows Server 2008 R2.  The domain controller is running on Hyper-V.  Of course I can ping the FQDN internally on the Domain controller but not the host server.

When pinging the Netbios name from host the DNS resolves and ping is successful.  When pinging using using FQDN (server1.contoso.local) I receive Ping request could not find host server1.contoso.local. Please check the name and try again.

I have done nothing to the network besides setting up the Active Directory.  IP6 is disabled.  The server and DC have static IPs and my router is the DHCP provider.  The DC is DNS.

setup is as follows:

```
                 IP: 192.168.0.199

                 Subnet: 255.255.255.0

                 Default gateway: 192.168.0.1 (router internal IP)

                 Preferred DNS: 192.168.0.100 (DC IP)

                 Alternate: 192.168.0.1
```

When I attempt to join the domain I have to use the Netbios name (FQDN will not work; could not contact active directory domain controller).  I am prompted to enter domain password but then receive the following error: "The following error occurred attempting to join the domain "domain-name"  An attempt to resolve the dns name of a domain controller in the domain being joined has failed.  Please verify this client is configured to reach a DNS server that can resolve DNS names in the target domain."

I have disabled the firewal on both the host server and the DC.  I have attempted a /flushdns and a /registerdns.  No changes.  When attempting to renew the ipconfig on the DC I receive the following error: "An error occurred while releasing interface Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1: the system cannot find the file specified"

Is my problem simply a missing DNS entry?  I unfortunately do not know much about DNS.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just resolved my issue.  One key bit of information I completely forgot to mention was that I have 2 NICs installed and in use on my server.  One of them is assigned strictly to the VM Domain Controller.  Because of this a virtual network connection was created.  For some reason that I don't entirely understand this was affecting my ability to see the FQDN on my network.  I corrected the DNS settings on the virtual NIC and all my NETBIOS woes have left.

I don't really understand why that caused the problem, but changing the virtual NIC DNS server settings which defaulted to my router instead of my DC fixed the problem.

Comment: I have the exact same problem as @HawkeyeD and I get the same message when I try to join my computer to Domain! But I don't have a problem with my NIC, I've been dealing with this problem for almost a week now and it's really getting on my nerve now! So, please somebody help me with it!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue on my end by adding the domain name suffix to the host's NIC.